# Scraping nested span Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I'm trying to scrape the details of my favorite foods, I'm able to get the name and prices but the description is proving to be a challenge as the text is nested within a spans. I've tried a combination of this but not seem to give me the description.

Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
menu = doc.css('.menu-index-page__item-content').map do |menu|

  meal_name                   = menu.at_css('.menu-index-page__item-title span[1]').text.strip
  meal_price                  = menu.at_css('.menu-index-page__item-price').text.strip
  meal_des                  = menu.css('p.menu-index-page__item-desc span[3]').text.strip.to_s
```

Event1.new   meal_name,
            meal_price,
            meal_des
    end
pp menu

returns

```
#<struct Event1
  meal_name="chicken Burger",
  meal_price="£3.95",
  meal_des="">,
```

The HTML i'm trying to scrape is below:

```
<div class="menu-index-page__item-content" data-reactid=".1446l8bfnk0.3.5.0.4:$648324.2.$4885079.$menuItemContent">

<h6 class="menu-index-page__item-title" data-reactid=".1446l8bfnk0.3.5.0.4:$648324.2.$4885079.$menuItemContent.0"><span data-reactid=".1446l8bfnk0.3.5.0.4:$648324.2.$4885079.$menuItemContent.0.1">Chicken Burger</span></h6>
<p class="menu-index-page__item-desc" data-reactid=".1446l8bfnk0.3.5.0.4:$648324.2.$4885079.$menuItemContent.1"><span data-reactid=".1446l8bfnk0.3.5.0.4:$648324.2.$4885079.$menuItemContent.1.0">
<span data-reactid=".1446l8bfnk0.3.5.0.4:$648324.2.$4885079.$menuItemContent.1.0"><span data-reactid=".1446l8bfnk0.3.5.0.4:$648324.2.$4885079.$menuItemContent.1.0.0"><span data-reactid=".1446l8bfnk0.3.5.0.4:$648324.2.$4885079.$menuItemContent.1.0.0.0:$0">Chargrilled chicken thigh with</span>
<br data-reactid=".1446l8bfnk0.3.5.0.4:$648324.2.$4885079.$menuItemContent.1.0.0.0:$0br"><span data-reactid=".1446l8bfnk0.3.5.0.4:$648324.2.$4885079.$menuItemContent.1.0.0.$1">fresh herb olive oil mayonnaise.</span></span>
<span style="position:fixed;visibility:hidden;top:0;left:0;" data-reactid=".1446l8bfnk0.3.5.0.4:$648324.2.$4885079.$menuItemContent.1.0.2">…</span></span></p>
<span class="menu-index-page__item-price" data-reactid=".1446l8bfnk0.3.5.0.4:$648324.2.$4885079.$menuItemContent.2">£3.55</span>
```

I'm trying to get 
Chargrilled chicken thigh with
fresh herb olive oil mayonnaise.

as the description, I'm not sure why span[3] is not giving me any results.

Comment: There is some truncated content in the HTML you pasted. What is that? See this: `"$menuItemContent.1.0.2">…</span></span></p>"`

Comment: You want to look at the source for a big json object that react initializes with.

Answer (score 0):

With little knowledge of [`nokogiri`](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri), i don't know the best approach to do this, but this is how i extracted the text out of given HTML:

```
# I assume you can get this HTML by doing `menu.css('p.menu-index-page__item-desc').something`
desc_html = '<span data-reactid=".1446l8bfnk0.3.5.0.4:$648324.2.$4885079.$menuItemContent.1.0">
               <span data-reactid=".1446l8bfnk0.3.5.0.4:$648324.2.$4885079.$menuItemContent.1.0">
                 <span data-reactid=".1446l8bfnk0.3.5.0.4:$648324.2.$4885079.$menuItemContent.1.0.0">
                   <span data-reactid=".1446l8bfnk0.3.5.0.4:$648324.2.$4885079.$menuItemContent.1.0.0.0:$0">Chargrilled chicken thigh with</span>
                   <br data-reactid=".1446l8bfnk0.3.5.0.4:$648324.2.$4885079.$menuItemContent.1.0.0.0:$0br">
                   <span data-reactid=".1446l8bfnk0.3.5.0.4:$648324.2.$4885079.$menuItemContent.1.0.0.$1">fresh herb olive oil mayonnaise.</span>
                 </span>
                 <span style="position:fixed;visibility:hidden;top:0;left:0;" data-reactid=".1446l8bfnk0.3.5.0.4:$648324.2.$4885079.$menuItemContent.1.0.2"></span>
               </span>
             </span>'

doc = Nokogiri.parse(desc_html)

doc.children.text
 => "\n  \n    \n      Chargrilled chicken thigh with\n      \n      fresh herb olive oil mayonnaise.\n    \n    \n    \n  \n"

doc.children.text.strip
 => "Chargrilled chicken thigh with\n      \n      fresh herb olive oil mayonnaise."

doc.children.text.strip.gsub(/\W{2,}/, ' ')
 => "Chargrilled chicken thigh with fresh herb olive oil mayonnaise."
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply, I should have been clearer the html is just a snippet of the whole html page, the html I've provided is the section of the page i'm interested in. when I try 'doc.children.text ' if gives me all the child elements for the whole page.

Comment: In my answer, `doc` does not represent whole page, but only the description section.

Comment: To be more clear, try `doc = menu.css('p.menu-index-page__item-desc')` or something that would return the Nokogiri element for description section.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```ruby
# ...
menu = doc.css('.menu-index-page__item-content')
menu.map { |m| m.css('span')[2].text  }
# => ["Chargrilled chicken thigh with\nfresh herb olive oil mayonnaise.\n…"]
```